# Call a method of session beans that deployed on the remote machine

Tags: java, session, glassfish, ejb, javabeans

I wrote a EJB session beans and deployed it on the GlassFish application server. i can call it easily with @EJB annotation from a local JSF web application but i dont know how to call it from a JSF web application that deployed on the remote machine (another machine).
can i dot this with @EJB annotation and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accessing EJB Components in a Remote Application Server](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4336/beanv?l=en&a=view) for GlassFish 2.1.

[Accessing EJB Components in a Remote Enterprise Server](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7695/beanv?l=en&a=view) for GlassFish v3.